# Compare Two columns If 2 cells are Matching

Tags: excel, match

My intention is to check if the value on E6 and F6(together) are matching the values on B6 and C6(together). For ex. if (AA28E and 0.25) is matching with the values on column E and F, the A column will be blank otherwise it will add "d" string.

How should I correct the formula ?

[image]

Comment: You mean E6 and F6 (not F8)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is hard to follow but I'll give it a shot.
If you only want to compare values with in the single row use and not look at a different row use:

`=IF(AND(B3=D3,C3=E3),"","d")`

If want to know if the values in one row of E&F match exactly the rows of columns B&C use `COUNTIFS()`.

`=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,D3,C:C,E3)>0,"","d")`

Comment: If the values on one row of column B&C exists in entire E&F column. cell will be blank otherwise it will be "d". For example: since Column B&C 17(AA28E %) is not existing on entire E&F column it should add "d" . There is AA28E 4 , AA28E 6 but there is not AA28E 5 on E&F columns.

Comment: @MuratKarınca, Got it so you just need to rearrange the equation that I sent you. `=IF(COUNTIFS(D:D,B5,E:E,C5)>0,"","d")`

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this in Excel recently, but should work according to your comments to the previous answers.

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(1,(D:D=B1)*(E:E=C1),0), ""), "d")
```

Comment: This solution does work the same as `=IF(COUNTIFS(D:D,B5,E:E,C5)>0,"","d")`

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(AND(E6=B6,F6=C6),"","d")`

Comment: If the values on one row of column B&C exists in entire E&F column. cell will be blank otherwise it will be "d". For example: since Column B&C 17(AA28E %) is not existing on entire E&F column it should add "d" . There is AA28E 4 , AA28E 6 but there is not AA28E 5 on E&F columns.

Comment: @MuratKarınca You should edit the question to fix that mistake in the specifications you give -- that you want to do a lookup instead of a row-by-row comparison.